# MySQL/PHP: Database Layout, Sorting, and Searching

Tags: php, mysql

On my website, for members of my service I provide a contact database where they can store all their contacts. This database is suppose to be more tailored fit for the member. When entering a contact it asks all the standard questions like names and titles, then stores them in table `contacts`. Then come the additional fields like phone, address, email, and website. But contacts can multiples of those, so I want my members to be able to enter unlimited. I did this by making a table for each field, `contacts_phone, contacts_address, contacts_email, contacts_website`and each row had the id, parent, and data.

This made it extremely hard for me to get a proper search going. The only way these extra fields are connected is through `parent` which holds the ID of the contact it is connected to.
It also cause some other bugs and errors so I decided to trash that idea and considered it a failure.

Now I've decided to limit the member on entering up to 10 multiples of each field. So in table `contacts` it now has hundreds of columns (phone_1_data, photo_2_data, phone_3_data, ect.) and just seems messy and wrong. It will be so much easier to search through, sort, and interact with but it doesn't seem like the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any custom columns, add a simple key-value table, with the contact ID, a string key, and a string value. You can use this to match arbitrary numbers of arbitrary custom fields to the contacts, and they'll remain searchable using `JOIN`s.

```
CREATE TABLE `custom_fields` (
    `contact_id` INT,
    `key` VARCHAR(63),
    `value` VARCHAR(255)
);
```

To get all the extra fields for a contact:

```
SELECT `key`, `value` FROM `custom_fields` WHERE `contact_id` = ?
```

To search for a contact with a particular value in a particular custom field:

```
SELECT `contact`.* FROM `contacts`
JOIN `custom_fields` ON `custom_fields`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id`
WHERE `custom_fields`.`key` = ? AND `custom_fields`.`value` = ?
```

Or, to find a contact with a particular value in any custom field:

```
SELECT `contact`.* FROM `contacts`
JOIN `custom_fields` ON `custom_fields`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id`
WHERE `custom_fields`.`value` = ?
```

Comment: I'm not very educated with MySQL and I'm somewhat confused by this answer. Is there anyway you could show an example?

Comment: Thank you, I still don't understand 'JOIN' completely. Even seeing your example confuses me but I'll go spend some time studying it so that I can learn to use it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track storing repeatable elements in a separate table. Why did it become "extremely hard ... to get a proper search going"?

Joining on parent id should have got you what you waned. Perhaps you just needed another column to sort, or key off of for the detail tables?

parent_id, data_desc, data
'123','mobile1','123.456.7890'

Adding new columns to the contact row will cause you more pain in the long run. Look up "Database Normalization" for table design ideas that will work best for you.

Comment: My biggest weakness is MySQL. I still don't understand the concept of 'JOIN' or how I would use it. You and Adrian have helped me realize I need to educate myself on it because it seems to be the way to go in this case. Thank you.